# Set blank password for Login keyring through command line only

Tags: ubuntu, login, gnome-keyring

Want to set blank password for Login keyring through command line and not through passwords and Keys. Case of automatic login and don't need to be bothered by keyring pass popup .Came across multiple docs using seahorse but I need to achieve using command line. Secret-tool isn't working for me

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any suggestions anyone? Can we disable login keyring by deleting keyrings @ /.local/share/keyrings?

Comment: you are correct! I was face this problem, and after deleting the 2 files inside the mentioned folder, then restart, the popup didn't appear again! Thanks a lot!